# Simple PAM example

Tags: c, linux, pam

I want to develop an authentication module using PAM, but I'm having trouble getting a simple example working.

For starters, I would like to do a simple SSH login system where if the user enters the username `backdoor`, then the user will be logged in without a password (just like in TRON Legacy).

I tried using [this guide](http://ben.akrin.com/?p=1068) as a template, but I can't get it to work.  Here is my code so far:

```
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS ;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
    int retval;

    printf("I'm here");

    const char* pUsername;
    retval = pam_get_user(pamh, &pUsername, "Username: ");
    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        return retval;
    }

    if (strcmp(pUsername, "backdoor") != 0) {
        return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
    }
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I log in with the name `backdoor`, I get permission denied. I've tried creating the user account, but I still get prompted for the password.

When I log in with a valid user, I see the "I'm here" printout.  Is there a better way to debug something like this or is it mostly trial and error?

EDIT:

I added this to my `/etc/pam.d/sshd` after @include common-auth:

`auth sufficient mypam.so`

This comes after 2 other .so files, but I'm pretty sure it's getting executed every time.

I have not modified pam.conf (there isn't anything there). I figured that starting with SSH would be easiest because I don't have to log out each time.

EDIT:

I finally got it working. Here's the result:

https://github.com/beatgammit/simple-pam

It's open-source, so if you're interested, take a look!

Comment: Thanks for telling us about the backdoor. ;-) But you may be able to do this with just a different rule set and configurations using existing modules.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not my end goal. I eventually want to make an HTTP-based auth system, but I figure that I need to get something simple set up first to build off of.

Comment: Well, you could also do that in the same way. But I'm curious now what you mean by that. HTTP auth system front end, or back end?

Comment: Uh, backend.  I want to have credentials on a webserver. It's part of a bigger project, but basically I want to have a roaming auth system instead of relying on /etc/passwd entries. I know it's possible because I've seen examples, but I'm just having trouble getting a simple example working.

Comment: Like LDAP, but customized. Think of having a login system based on OpenID or OAuth or something. That's kind of what I want to achieve. I can do all of the backend stuff (including security), but I have no experience with PAM.

Comment: Ah, cool. that's some serious roaming, then. :-) Then probably a good place to start is to get the source code for PAM and study it.

Comment: I'll probably start by making a Node.js module for PAM. There aren't any yet, and I think it would be pretty useful (plus I like JS better than C anyway...)

Comment: That would be great. I just started learning Node.js myself.

Comment: Cool. I post stuff on GitHub, and if I get this module working well, I'll be sure to brag about it everywhere =D It'll all be open-source of course.

Comment: What pam configuration (`pam.conf` or `pam.d/*` lines) are you using this with? Add some tracing output just before each `return`, to see what precisely is happening. Could it be that your module is returning `PAM_SUCCESS` but then some other required module is saying no?

Comment: sshd isn't just authentication. You also need account and session permission, which you're not providing. You're actually making a more complex case then your HTTP auth goal.

Comment: @Mel Hmm.. I guess maybe I am. I just wanted to test it, and I assumed that SSH would be easier, but what you said makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, sufficient will still fail if a previous required module has failed.  Since you say you have put your sufficient line beneath the include of common-auth you may be seeing a failure because some required module in common-auth has denied access already.  Plus you have have sshd getting in the way.

I'd get all this stuff out of the way so you know your test is really a test of your pam module and not some further interaction with other things.  I'd start with a simple test program like the one [here](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-example.html) with /etc/pam.d/check_user listing your module instead of pam_unix.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at that. That will probably be easier than trying to get behind all of the SSH stuff.

Comment: You got me on the right track and I got a simple example working. Thanks so much!

Comment: I know this answer is pretty old, but unfortunately the link is dead :(